# How to have an object stored as a string in a string parameter of a rest webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am using a REST webservice, Can i have a flexible string parameter in a webservice which can accept any object stored as a string.

For example i have this sample RequestJson:

```
public class RequestJSON {
    String username;
    String password;
    String data;
}
```

In the data parameter i want to accept any json object,

```
@Path("/rest")
public class RESTWebservice {
    @POST
    @Path("/request")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseJSON sampleWeb(RequestJSON requestJson) {
        logger.info(requestJson.toString());
    }
}
```

How we can make webservice to accept any json to be sent in the data parameter of the request Json:

For example like this:

```
{
"username":"abc",
"password":"xyz",
"data":{"number":"4","input":"","msg":{"msgArr":["hello","test"]}},
}
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `@RequestBody` annotation before the parameter declaration: `@RequestBody RequestJSON requestJson`.

Comment: Is there something not working with you current implementation?

Comment: You might want to consider making it a `Map<String, Object>` if you want to do any useful manipulation of the data. You will need to have some idea about the structure to traverse the map correctly though. Different values will produce different types for the `Object` value.

Comment: @christopher `@RequestBody` belongs to Spring, am I wrong? OP seems to use JAX-WS.

Comment: @sp00m My apologies. I've got one too many frameworks swimming about in my head!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    enum DATATYPE {
        STRING,
        FLOAT,
        INTEGER,
        BOOLEAN; // could add lists but then it gets nasty because you have to have a delimiter
    }

    class ColectionOfData {
        List<DATA> data;
    }

    class DATA  { 
        String name;
        DATATYPE datatype; // form should inform of the data type
        String data;

        public DATA(String name, DATATYPE datatype, String data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.datatype = datatype;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Object convert() {
            switch(datatype) {
            case BOOLEAN:
                return Boolean.parseBoolean(data);
            case FLOAT:
                return Float.parseFloat(data);
            case INTEGER:
                return Integer.parseInt(data);
            case STRING:
                return data;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But it's not pretty. You can make it less ugly, but it will always be ugly.